# How to submit radio button value + additional info about the form to Redux

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux

This is a bit longwinded so I'll do my best to explain clearly.

I'm making a simple poll app and on the home page is an array of polls where you can vote on each poll.

Each poll is on a card and there will be different radio buttons representing the different voting options for that poll.

I'm trying to set up a form for each poll which contains radio button inputs for each of the different options and push that `onSubmit` to an action creator.

However, I would also like to pass that title of the poll as well as an argument to the action creator so that I can create a single action creator that will help me submit the votes for all the polls. Something like `submitVote(title, option)`.

Here is my polls page:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import Loading from '../Loading';

class MyPolls extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      skip: 0,
      isLoading: true,
      isLoadingMore: false,
      value: ''
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchMyPolls(this.state.skip)
      .then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
            skip: this.state.skip + 4,
            isLoading: false
          });
        }, 1000);
      });
  }

  sumVotes(acc, cur) {
    return acc.votes + cur.votes
  }

  loadMore(skip) {
    this.setState({ isLoadingMore: true });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.fetchMyPolls(skip)
        .then(() => {
          const nextSkip = this.state.skip + 4;
          this.setState({
            skip: nextSkip,
            isLoadingMore: false
          });
        });
    }, 1000);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  renderPolls() {
    return this.props.polls.map(poll => {
      return (
        <div className='card' key={poll._id} style={{ width: '350px', height: '400px' }}>
          <div className='card-content'>
            <span className='card-title'>{poll.title}</span>
            <p>Total votes: {poll.options.reduce((acc, cur) => { return acc + cur.votes }, 0)}</p>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              {poll.options.map(option => {
                return (
                  <p key={option._id}>
                    <input
                      name={poll.title}
                      className='with-gap'
                      type='radio'
                      id={option._id}
                      value={option.option}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor={option._id}>
                      {option.option}
                    </label>
                  </p>
                )
              })}

              <button
                type='text'
                className='activator teal btn waves-effect waves-light'
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  bottom: '10%',
                  transform: 'translateX(-50%)'
                }}
                >
                Submit
                <i className='material-icons right'>
                  send
                </i>
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className='card-reveal'>
            <span className='card-title'>{poll.title}
              <i className='material-icons right'>close</i>
            </span>
            <p>
              dsfasfasdf
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='center-align container'>
        <h2>My Polls</h2>
        {this.state.isLoading ? <Loading size='big' /> :
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', alignItems: 'center', alignContent: 'center' }}>
          {this.renderPolls()}
        </div>}
        <div className='row'>
          {this.state.isLoadingMore ? <Loading size='small' /> :
          <button
            className='btn red lighten-2 wave-effect waves-light' onClick={() => this.loadMore(this.state.skip)}>
            Load More
          </button>}
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ polls }) {
  return { polls }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(MyPolls);
```

Demo of the app so far: https://voting-app-drhectapus.herokuapp.com/

(use `riverfish@gmail.com` and password `123` to login).

Github repo: https://github.com/drhectapus/Voting-App

I'd like to program it so that when form is submitted via `this.handleSubmit`, the `handleSubmit` function can take 2 arguments, `title` and `option` and pass that onto an action creator in redux.

How do I do this?

Comment: `<form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(poll.title, e)}>`. You can get the selected option from the event, but looks like you are saving the value in state anyway using onChange.

Comment: how do I get the option from the event?

Comment: Well, technically you can get all form elements from the submit event since `e.target` will be an array of form elements. However, you are saving the selected element in state, so just get it from state.

Comment: Just realised it's not ideal to save value in state using `onChange` because i'm rendering multiple polls on the same page so if I click an option on one poll and submit on another it submits an option for the wrong poll. I tried console logging `e.target` and I can see the HTML for the entire form, but no way to tell which radio button is checked or not

Comment: `console.log(e.target.id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little difficult to understand everything going on here, but I get the sense that your main goal is to pass two args to `this.handleSubmit`. You may instead consider just passing `poll.title` and grabbing the selected `option` from `state`. Try something like this:

```
this.handleSubmit(title) {

    // this.state.value should already have the selected option!    
    let obj = {
        title,
        option: this.state.value
    };

    // dispatch the object to redux, update your reducer, etc.
}
```

And in your `render`, be sure to `bind` `poll.title` as the argument:

```
render() {
    ...
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this, poll.title)}>
}
```

Does that help at all? Let me know if I'm totally missing the mark on what you intend. With `.bind()` you pass the `this` context to use followed by a list of common separated args, so you could pass multiple args, but it's much easier to just grab `option` from `state` in this case.

**Edit**

If you want to access the `SyntheticEvent` that gets fired on `submit`, you simple specify it as the second argument to `this.handleSubmit` like so:

```
this.handleSubmit(title, event) {
    // prevent form submit
    event.preventDefault();
}

// this is the exact same as above, no need to pass event
render() {
    ...
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this, poll.title)}>
}
```

In React, synthetic events are always passed as the last argument to a bound function and simply need to be specified to be in the method definition (no need to specify in `render`). This is `Function.prototype.bind` way of working with functions and events in React. Here are the supporting docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers

Comment: Yes that's the general idea but I'd also like to access `event` in the `handleSubmit` handler because i want to call `event.preventDefault()` so entire component is not re-rendered upon submit. How do i do that?

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer, the Edit section should answer the above!